# Android contatcs vcard API

Tags: android

Is there any android API to extract contacts in vcard 3.0 format ?
I have come across an open-source vcard project [android-vcard](http://code.google.com/p/android-vcard/)

but in the **usage Example** the following comments are mentioned.

**Important:** If you are developing application for Android device, you don't have to use this library, because it is already included in the underlying Android framework. This library is useful only if you are developing application to be run outside of Android environment. Android developers: read this text twice.

Can you please let me know which library is mentioned in the above description? 
Is it made available to the application developers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works with Eclair (>= Android 2.0) and I guess its somewhat this functionality the examples page describes

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
AssetFileDescriptor fd = resolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
byte[] b = new byte[(int)fd.getDeclaredLength()];
fis.read(b);
String vCard = new String(b);
sb.append(vCard);
```

Comment: @Schildmeijer What's sb in the last line??