# How to get android contacts in Vcard format using android native API

Tags: android, vcf-vcard

I am trying to read Android device contacts in VCard format using Android Api.
i found one link for the same:
[Android contatcs vcard API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243784/android-contatcs-vcard-api)

and trying to write the same code but its not working, as I am not able to get the lookupkey:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);  
int num = cur.getCount();  // I get 2 , as there are two contacts

String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
// The above line gives error : android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException:
//  Index -1 requested, with a size of 2

Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
AssetFileDescriptor fd = resolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
    byte[] b = new byte[(int)fd.getDeclaredLength()];
fis.read(b);
String vCard = new String(b);
sb.append(vCard);
```

Can anyone please tell me how to get the lookupkey for the above code or there is any other way we can get contacts VCard format using Android api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- Edit 2 ---

It looks like you are not doing cur.moveToFirst() before reading cursor, so you are getting exceptiion. try look into [android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481895/android-database-cursorindexoutofboundsexception-index-1-requested) which describes the same problem.

-- Edited answer --

[LookUpKey](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html) in the code is for a specific contact. The conde example you are using is to get the vcard for a specific contact. you have to loop though the available contacts and inside you can put the code you have to get it working. You can get look up key from contact contract.

apart from that, you should consider following a general solution:

1. Please add error that you got in `logcat`
2. have you added contact permission in application manifest to allow application to read contacts?

Comment: I am looking for how to get LOOKUPKEY in Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);

Comment: You are right I am requesting for lookup key using cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));  as mentioned above but its giving exception : android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 2
, is there anything wrong in starting ContactComtract code , please explain.

Comment: In your code, you have to do cur.moveToNext() before you read contact, that will fix the index problem

Answer (score 7):

Here you are:

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    try {
        do {
            String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));


            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI,
                    lookupKey);
            AssetFileDescriptor fd;
            try {
                fd = context.getContentResolver()
                        .openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
                FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
                byte[] b = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
                fis.read(b);
                String vCard = new String(b);
                Log.i(TAG, vCard);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `context cannot be resolved` for the line `fd = context.getContentResolver()`.

Comment: Changing it to `fd = getContentResolver()` gives no immediate errors.

Comment: Works on SGS 2 (Android 4.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void getVCF() {
    final String vfile = "Contacts.csv";
    Cursor phones = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);
    phones.moveToFirst();

    do {
        String lookupKey = phones.getString(phones
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));

        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
        AssetFileDescriptor fd;
        try {
            fd = mContext.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri,
                    "r");
            FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
            fis.read(buf);
            String VCard = new String(buf);
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString() + File.separator + vfile;
            FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path,
                    true);
            mFileOutputStream.write(VCard.toString().getBytes());
            phones.moveToNext();
            Log.d("Vcard", VCard);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    } while (phones.moveToNext());

}
```